# Is it safe to store Tweet IDs as BIGINTs?

Tags: mysql, twitter

Moving forwards, am I going to have a problem at some point if I store Tweet IDs from the Twitter API as an unsigned BIGINT in MySQL?

Am I better off using a CHAR(25) or something? The Tweet IDs are only going to get bigger and bigger over time.

Comment: If Twitter ID is an integer and if you use BIGINT for storage - you use 8 bytes. If you use CHAR(25) you use 25 bytes but you can store alphanumerics. I think you can take it from there :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

an unsigned bigint can hold a value in the range of 0 to 18446744073709551615 (a really big number)

if there are say approx. 52 billion tweets per year then:

```
18446744073709551615 / 52000000000 = 354745078 years worth of tweets
```

so I think you'd be safe :P

Comment: Put another way: if all 7e9 people on the planet tweeted once every second, you'd exhaust the 1.8e19 ID space after about 81 years.

Comment: but the question still remains, does twitter openly confirm id's are 64bit integers?

Answer (score 4):

They confirm id-s are 64-bit integers at this blog post from 2010: https://blog.twitter.com/2010/announcing-snowflake